# Memcache not setting value "<script>"

Tags: memcached

I'm trying to set a memcache key with a value that looks like this:

```
<script>
```

Although setting the key is successful, when we try to get the key, it is empty. Setting this value is no problem.

```
script>
```

Is it **a bug** or a **known limitation** in memcache that you cannot set values with "<>" in it? Or **something else**?

Memcache version 1.4.21.

Answer (score 0):

This is because memcache client is internally converting < to &lt to prevent malicious code from executing. As a practice setting a key with <,> is a bad idea.

Comment: Couldn't be the case because it's impossible to set the key with that value. It sets the key with an empty value. Maybe it's our particular version of memcache but i would prefer "false" than setting an empty key. Or a key with a conversion.